# Documentation on PHP Function <<< OUT

Tags: php

I am looking for documentation on PHP <<< OUT

What exactly does this do and maybe an example of it's use.

Example:

```
<?php

    echo <<<OUT
        <table>
            <tr></tr>
            <td></td>
        </table>
    OUT;

?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: look up `Nowdoc` and `heredoc`

Comment: Please, consider reading PHP documentation about [Heredoc Syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

Answer (score 1):

This is [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). Manual is your friend